# Android Studio create another layout folder

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, besides the default layout folder, I need to create layout-land for different layout in landscape mode. However I couldn't add a new folder. I've tried some ways such as right click -> new -> Directory,  right click -> new -> Android resource directory, right click -> new -> Folder but all of them didn't work at all. What is the appropriate way to create a new layout folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the left on Android studio there where you can see all your classes and packages you can see on top a selector. try altering that selector to show Project rather than your app if this is the situation.

Sometimes when you show only app contents resource folders are somehow hidden when they are empty but when you switch to project view most of the times are visible.

Comment: Right clicking from the res folder is working. I just checked.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on ***layout*** folder -> New -> Layout resource file
Choose ***Orientation*** in bottom frame and select ***Landscape***